# Geb+Spock tests can't reuse content c'tors, fail with MissingMethodException

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I've only recently started creating Geb/Spock tests for our web app and -- given my limited knowledge of Geb, Spock, and all things Groovy -- have bumped into an error that makes no sense whatsoever (given my Java experience).

So, here is the module in question:

```
import geb.Module
import geb.navigator.Navigator

class Tile extends Module {

    def currencyPair

    static content = {

        amount { 
            $(".currencypair-span", text: containsWord(currencyPair))
                .parent().parent()
                .find(".tile-amount-setup").find("input") }     
    }       
 }
```

Nothing extraordinary there.

Here is the page (I'm not sure how this all fits together, though):

```
import geb.Page

class TraderApp extends Page {

    static url = "./"

    static at = { title == "FOOBARTrader" }

    static content = {
        tile { instrument -> module Tile, currencyPair: instrument }
    }

}
```

Here is the test spec:

```
import geb.spock.GebSpec

import spock.lang.*
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys

class BugSpec extends SbkSpec {

    final CURPAIR = "FOOBAR"

    def setupSpec() {
        accountSelector.dropDown.click()

        accountSelector.dropDown << Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a")
        accountSelector.dropDown << "FxOnly"
        accountSelector.dropDown << Keys.ENTER

        waitFor() { accountSelector.dropDown.value() == "FXOnly" }

        tileLayout("Majors").tab.click()
    }

    def "test1"() {
        given:
            tile(CURPAIR).amount.click()

        when: 
            println("foo")

        then:
            waitFor {true}            
    }

    def "test2"() {
        given:
            tile(CURPAIR).amount.click()

        when: println("bar")

        then:
            waitFor {true} 
    }
}
```

Now, the issue is that the first test will run and pass, but when the second test is run **the JVM will report a NoSuchMethodException on the tile() method**.

How is this possible? I appreciate that Groovy is a dynamic language, but where is the method disappearing to?

This makes it impossible for me to reuse content in several different tests, as the content in question is unreachable once I exit the first test that uses it.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running BugSpec
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.10.267521) on port 32075
Only local connections are allowed.
foo
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 19.425 sec <<< FAILURE!
test2(BugSpec)  Time elapsed: 0.175 sec  <<< ERROR!
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.tile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [FOOBAR]
Possible solutions: size(), tail(), filter(java.lang.String), find(java.lang.String), is(java.lang.String), take(int)
        at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.methodMissing(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:463)
        at geb.content.NavigableSupport.methodMissing(NavigableSupport.groovy:123)
        at geb.Browser.methodMissing(Browser.groovy:194)
        at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:51)
        at BugSpec.test2(BugSpec.groovy:35)
```

Help please?

**EDIT:**

As per Erdi's answer, included is also the superclass of BugSpec:

```
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec

class SbkSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def setupSpec() {
        def environment = System.getProperty("geb.env");

        given:
            to AuthApp                

        expect:
            at AuthApp                

        when:
            def username = browser.getConfig().getRawConfig().get("username")
            def password = browser.getConfig().getRawConfig().get("password")

            login.username.value(username)
            login.password.value(password)

            login.loginButton.click()

        then:
            at TraderApp
            and:
                waitFor() { accountSelector.dropDown.value() == "FOOBAR-ACCOUNT" }
    }

    def cleanupSpec() {
        given:
            at TraderApp
        then:
            logout.logoutButton.click()
    }        
}
```

Comment: There's no such method in the docs: http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/Page.html. Why You claim it's 'disappearing'? The `tail` method invocation is redirected to instance of this interface: http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/navigator/Navigator.html via this class: http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/content/PageContentSupport.html

Comment: Please read the question again, @Opal . The first call to `tile()` succeeds and the first test passes (note the "`foo`" printed in the `TESTS` output), but the second invocation of the same method fails, throwing the exception.

How can one call work but the second call to the same method claims the method does not exist?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Interesting. Is there any chance to reproduce?

Comment: Hard to say because base class etc. are missing, but chances are that the setup is incorrect, and `TraderApp` isn't the current page at the start of the second test (`setupSpec` will only run before the first test`).

Comment: @Peter, which other classes should I provide in the question? I'm very fuzzy about Geb and even more confused with Groovy at the moment, so I don't have the right mental model to understand how all the classes and method calls fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the built-in base `GebSpec`/`GebReportingSpec` Geb dispatches missing method calls to the `page` property of spec's `browser` property. Something (without seeing more code it's impossible to say what exactly it is) sets that property to an instance of `TraderApp` before the first test. Geb recreates the `browser` instance between each test which means that the page instance is reset to the default which is an instance of `Page`. If you set the page to be an instance of `TraderApp` then `tile()` method will be found:

```
def "test2"() {
    given:
        page TraderApp
        tile(CURPAIR).amount.click()

    when: println("bar")

    then:
        waitFor {true} 
}
```

It would be way easier to reason about things and help out if you provided code for the chain of all superclasses of `BugSpec` up to the one that extends `GebSpec`/`GebReportingSpec`. Looks to me like you might be dealing with a smell where the tests are setup in way where their execution order matters.

Comment: Hi, @Erdi. Thanks a lot for the feedback. I have updated the question to include the code for the super class of BugSpec. :-) Also, the suggested fix (adding the `page TraderApp` line) does not seem to have fixed the issue. I hope the extra code will help.

Comment: Ah, I lied. The trick worked perfectly! I had to add the line to all the tests, as well as the `BugSpec`'s `setupSpec` method. :-D I will accept your answer, but hopefully you could figure out for us what the problem is in the superclass (the code smell), please?

Comment: I don't think that there is any code smell there. All your code in `setupSpec()`s should actually be in `setup()` methods. This is because the browser state is reset between test methods and all cookies are removed from it. This is why you always want to login and explicitly go to pages instead of expecting to be the browser in any particular state after the previous test. Some people believe this is excessive and try to manage browser state, but this essentially leads to interdependent and brittle tests. I personally believe that you should start every test from a clean state.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the illuminating comments, @Erdi. As someone dabbling in Haskell fucntional programming, I can appreciate your comment about eschewing keeping too much state between tests. But alas, that would make the test suite run slower. But I now have a better idea how Geb does things as well as how to tackle this issue; thanks a lot. :-D

Comment: If you do need your tests to run in order, you can add the @Stepwise annotation to the top of your spec. This will cause the features to be executed in the order they are defined, and Geb will not reset the browser between each test.

Comment: @jk47: perfect trick! Makes things a whole lot simpler. Thanks a lot!